# "docker:19.03-dind" could not select device driver "nvidia" with capabilities: [[gpu]]

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gpu, nvidia-docker, docker-in-docker

I got a K8S+DinD issue:

- launch Kubernetes cluster
- start a main docker image and a DinD image inside this cluster
- when running a job requesting GPU, got error `could not select device driver "nvidia" with capabilities: [[gpu]]`

Full error

```
http://localhost:2375/v1.40/containers/long-hash-string/start: Internal Server Error ("could not select device driver "nvidia" with capabilities: [[gpu]]")
```

`exec` to the DinD image inside of K8S pod, `nvidia-smi` is not available.

Some debugging and it seems it's due to the DinD is missing the Nvidia-docker-toolkit, I had the same error when I ran the same job directly on my local laptop docker, I fixed the same error by installing **nvidia-docker2** `sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-docker2`.

I'm thinking maybe I can try to install nvidia-docker2 to the DinD 19.03 (docker:19.03-dind), but not sure how to do it? By multiple stage docker build?

Thank you very much!

---

update:

pod spec:

```
spec:
    containers:
      - name: dind-daemon
        image: docker:19.03-dind
```

Comment: Your pod spec yaml file?

Comment: And you docker daemon in privileged mode ?  https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it working myself.

Referring to

- https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/375
- https://github.com/Henderake/dind-nvidia-docker

> First, I modified the ubuntu-dind image (https://github.com/billyteves/ubuntu-dind) to install nvidia-docker (i.e. added the instructions in the nvidia-docker site to the Dockerfile) and changed it to be based on nvidia/cuda:9.2-runtime-ubuntu16.04.

> Then I created a pod with two containers, a frontend ubuntu container and the a privileged docker daemon container as a sidecar. The sidecar's image is the modified one I mentioned above.

But since this post is 3 year ago from now, I did spent quite some time to match up the dependencies versions, repo migration over 3 years, etc.

My modified version of Dockerfile to build it

```
ARG CUDA_IMAGE=nvidia/cuda:11.0.3-runtime-ubuntu20.04
FROM ${CUDA_IMAGE}

ARG DOCKER_CE_VERSION=5:18.09.1~3-0~ubuntu-xenial


RUN apt-get update -q && \
    apt-get install -yq \
        apt-transport-https \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        gnupg-agent \
        software-properties-common && \
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add - && \
    add-apt-repository \
       "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
       $(lsb_release -cs) \
       stable"  && \
    apt-get update -q && apt-get install -yq docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

# https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/project/PACKAGERS.md#runtime-dependencies
RUN set -eux; \
    apt-get update -q && \
    apt-get install -yq \
        btrfs-progs \
        e2fsprogs \
        iptables \
        xfsprogs \
        xz-utils \
# pigz: https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/35697 (faster gzip implementation)
        pigz \
#        zfs \
        wget


# set up subuid/subgid so that "--userns-remap=default" works out-of-the-box
RUN set -x \
    && addgroup --system dockremap \
    && adduser --system -ingroup dockremap dockremap \
    && echo 'dockremap:165536:65536' >> /etc/subuid \
    && echo 'dockremap:165536:65536' >> /etc/subgid

# https://github.com/docker/docker/tree/master/hack/dind
ENV DIND_COMMIT 37498f009d8bf25fbb6199e8ccd34bed84f2874b

RUN set -eux; \
    wget -O /usr/local/bin/dind "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/docker/${DIND_COMMIT}/hack/dind"; \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dind


##### Install nvidia docker #####
# Add the package repositories
RUN curl -fsSL https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | apt-key add --no-tty -

RUN distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID) && \
    echo $distribution &&  \
    curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.list | \
      tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list

RUN apt-get update -qq --fix-missing

RUN apt-get install -yq nvidia-docker2

RUN sed -i '2i \ \ \ \ "default-runtime": "nvidia",' /etc/docker/daemon.json

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/bin/
COPY dockerd-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/dockerd-entrypoint.sh
RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/dockerd-entrypoint.sh /

VOLUME /var/lib/docker
EXPOSE 2375

ENTRYPOINT ["dockerd-entrypoint.sh"]
#ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "/shared/dockerd-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD []
```

When I use `exec` to login into the Docker-in-Docker container, I can successfully run `nvidia-smi` (which previously return not found error then cannot run any GPU resource related docker run)

Welcome to pull my image at `brandsight/dind:nvidia-docker`

Comment: Anyone else seeing this that decides to go with https://github.com/ehfd/nvidia-dind instead because it's much newer, it's missing cuda, so the gpu works, but cuda doesn't, all you have to do is swap the ubuntu base for the cuda base (or runtime still trying to figure that out)